# Shapley value calculation in the case of absent features

Tags: explainable-ai, interpretation

The basic assumption in Shapely value calculation (which is also known as situational importance) is the following:

$$
v_i(x) = f(x_1, ..., x_n) - E[f(x_1, ...,X_i,..., x_n)]
$$

that is, the contribution of the $i$th feature for the prediction of an instance $x$ is the difference between the prediction for $x$ and the expected prediction in the absence of the $i$th feature.

If $f$ is an additive model then

$$
v_i(x) = \beta_ix_i - \beta_iE[X_i]
$$

The most crucial aspect of this definition is how to calculate the prediction in the absence of a feature. According to this formulation, it is calculated by expected value that is averaging over the distribution of the absent feature's values. (Note that Shapley value calculation does this over all possible feature combinations but that is not directly related to my question).

My question is this: Is defining feature contributions in this way a plausible approach? Consider a simple example: Suppose that we have an additive model for house price prediction. We want to measure the contribution of the "size" feature for the prediction of a particular house. Further suppose that the size of the house happens to be the average value of all area values of all the houses. Then, in this case, according to the above definition the contribution of the "size" feature in the prediction of that instance is 0. So, according to the above definition, in the prediction of this particular house, the "area" feature has no contribution. Is this result plausible? Why?

Comment: I have some questions that I would like to ask before answering your question: (1) What exactly ist $v_i$? Is it the SHAP-Value? (2) If $v_i$ is the SHAP-Value, then what class of models are you considering? Note that the first equation already uses some independence assumptions. (3) Based on your text, I assume that you impute missing features? Is this correct? What else do you mean with missing features?

Comment: (1) $v_i(x)$ is the contribution of the $i$th feature for the prediction of instace $x$. It is not exactly SHAP value, SHAP values considers all coalitions. (3) Missing features are filled by sampling from the data in SHAP value calculation. You can look at the following paper about the details for this definition: Štrumbelj, Erik, and Igor Kononenko. "Explaining prediction models and individual predictions with feature contributions." Knowledge and information systems 41 (2014): 647-665.

Comment: So your question is not about SHAP / Shapley values, but about some other contribution function? Unfortunately, I have no access to the paper and do not know the details about that work. So I am unable to answer the question.

Comment: OK, thanks, but this function is the basis SHAP value calculations, it is not something completely unrelated.

Comment: Well, as you said, SHAP values take all subsets into account while this does not. But what troubles me more is, that - if I understand you correctly, you use feature contribution values for imputation and then you want to compute the feature contribution of these imputed values. Sounds like I should read the paper before saying anything about it.

Comment: The prediction in the absence of a feature is not simply the average value of the feature, as you have suggested. Rather, it is the average value of the feature weighted and summed over all possible combinations of feature values.

Comment: @Multivac Yes, that is true for Shapley value (I noted that in the question). My question is about what is called situational importance, which is related to Shapley values. More information can be found at Štrumbelj, Erik, and Igor Kononenko. "Explaining prediction models and individual predictions with feature contributions." Knowledge and information systems 41 (2014): 647-665.